# Undefined property in a Views PHP field

Tags: 7, views

I need to have a field with user's picture URL. I'm trying to build it with a Views PHP field.

The field's value is defined

```
$account = user_load($row->uid);
$uri = $account->picture->uri;
$url = image_style_url('avatar', $uri);
return $url;
```

It returns value I expect, but returns also a warning

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in __lambda_func() (line 2 of /home/testwww/web/informator/sites/all/modules/views_php/plugins/views/views_php_handler_field.inc (131): runtime-created function).

Do you have any idea on how to solve the issue or what exactly is the cause?

From what I've found out:

- it seems that the notice concerns `uri` attribute of `$account->picture.`.
- The result of `print_r($account->picture)` is

```
        stdClass Object
        (
            [fid] => 168
            [uid] => 58
            [filename] => picture-58-1310836862.jpg
            [uri] => public://portrait/picture-58-1310836862.jpg
            [filemime] => image/jpeg
            [filesize] => 49505
            [status] => 1
            [timestamp] => 1310836862
            [rdf_mapping] => Array
                (
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users who have not uploaded a picture (also the anonymous user) will not have any object set for `$account->picture`. You just need to check that there is an object available:

```
$uri = isset($account->picture->uri) ? $account->picture->uri : NULL;
```

`image_style_url()` will return a bogus URI when passed NULL. You'll want to handle this somehow.

Note:
The user picture is already available as a field, you don't need PHP to get it.

In views 3, you must first add the "Content: Author" relationship before the User fields (including one for the user picture) will show up.

Comment: I need user picture URL, not the picture itself. Unless there's a way to extract the URL from the picture field.

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Hey, how could I have forgotten about users without picture? Spending too much time on one thing makes my mind a little dumb. Thanks a lot for the tip!